# How can I pull messages from Activemq Asynchronously

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, java-ee-6

I want to write code for pulling messages from `Activemq`.I don't want to pull all the messages from `Activemq` at a time,because my requirement is whenever my Java Application receives 1 message from `Activemq`,based on message body I will find corresponding `HTTP Link` and forward to that Link. For this entire logic I wrote 2 `.java` files names are

MessageConsumer.java

MyListener.java

MessageConsumer.java file only for connection establishing.The corresponding code is in below.

```
 package PackageName;
 import java.io.IOException;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.jms.*;
 import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
 public class MessageConsumer extends HttpServlet {
@Override
protected void service(HttpServletRequest arg0, HttpServletResponse arg1)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
      //creating connectionfactory object for way
      ConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new        
      ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617");
     //establishing the connection b/w this Application and Activemq
     Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection();
     Session session=connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
     Queue queue=session.createQueue("MessageTesing");
     javax.jms.MessageConsumer consumer=session.createConsumer(queue);
     //fetching queues from Activemq
     MessageListener listener = new MyListener();
    consumer.setMessageListener(listener);
    connection.start();
    System.out.println("Press a key to terminate");
    }
  catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
 }
}
```

MyListener.java file is for triggering corresponding Applications.code is in below

```
package PackageName;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;
public class MyListener implements MessageListener {
public void onMessage(Message msg) {
    try {
        TextMessage msg1=(TextMessage)msg;
        //just for your understanding I mention dummy code
        System.out.println(msg1.getText());
        if (msg1.getText()=="Google") {
            System.out.println("Forwarding http link to Google");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Forwarding http link to Facebook");
        }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

in my post, I am triggering Google and Facebook links.But As far my requirements I will call my own Applications.each Application taking more than 20 min.So I want to pull messages one by one.once previous message process completed then only it will receive another message from `Activemq` .

But right know I am getting all the messages at a time.How can I fix this.I seen `Activemq-Hellowworld` program.I didn't understand.

Sorry I am new to `Java` technology.can anyone help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a **MessageListener**, then you are actually receiving messages asynchronously (in another **thread**).

You are probably looking for **synchronous** message reception, so try this in your **main thread**:

```java
final QueueReceiver queueReceiver = queueSession.createReceiver(queue);
queueConnection.start();

while (true) {
  Message message = queueReceiver.receive();
  // Process your message: insert the code from MyListener.onMessage here

  // Possibly add an explit message.acknowledge() here, 
  // if you want to make sure that in case of an exception no message is lost
  // (requires Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE, when you create the queue session)

  // Possibly terminate program, if a certain condition/situation arises
}
```

without a `MessageListener`.

`receive()` **blocks** until a message is available, so your main thread (and thus your program) waits in the `receive` method. If a message arrives, it will receive and process it.

*Update*

If you use

```
Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
```

then you should call

```
message.acknowledge()
```

after the message has been processed completely.

Whereas in case of `Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE` the message is removed from the queue immediately (and is therefore lost, if the program terminates whilte processing the message).

Comment: I integrated your code in my code, Even If I receive messages from `Activemq`, No of pending messages are not reducing in my `Activemq` console.Why it was happening like this.

Comment: `@Beryllium` I totally confusing because of this task.

Comment: @user2642355 That changes the question. I suggest rolling back to the old version of the question, and posting a separate question with the topic "How to design ...". In that question please describe the use case of your application (no technical stuff, just the process), and the implementation you have done so far (the servlet using a JMS receiver). The combination of using a JMS receiver in a servlet is probably not that what you want, so we need to have a look at it from the use case perspective.

Comment: I posted the another question . can you check the following link.
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147115/how-can-i-call-externalapplication-based-on-activemq-message-using-jms`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `MessageListener` you could use the `receive()` method in the `MessageConsumer` object. This way you only get one message each time you call the `receive()` method.

```
MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(destination); 
Message message = consumer.receive(1000);
```