# How can I call externalApplication based on Activemq message using JMS

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic, java-ee-6

I build 3 Applications,each Application takes more than 20 min for evaluation.I placed 3 files in the following directories

```
 ProjectcContextPath/WEB-INF/classes/PackageName/ExternalFileProcess.class

 ProjectcContextPath/JSPFiles/index.jsp

ProjectcContextPath/WEB-INF/classes/AnotherFile.class
```

I want to call these 3 Applications from another `Java` file name as `MessageConsumer.java`,based on message-head.These messages are fetching from `Activemq`.

I don't want to fetch all the messages at a time. once previous is completed then only it `MessageConsumer.java` fetch another message from `Activemq`.

For your better understanding I made some mock-ups.check them.After check that you guys will understand clearly.

workflow:

[image]

Xml data structure.

[image]

What I did:

1. I build final 3 Applications,they are working fine.
2. I wrote a function,If you pass xmlfilepath and Message-head values as a parameters,then it returns corresponding `ApplicationRealPath` tag value.

What I want to do:

1. I want to fetch message from `Activemq`
2. Find message-head from message
3. pass message-head and xml file path to another function.Getting corresponding `ApplicationRealPath` value .
4. and trigger that Application.
5. fetch one more message from `Activemq`,once previous triggered Application process is done

Really I am trying this from 3 days, still I didn't figure it out.I tried the following code.it's not working

```
   package PackageName;
   import java.io.IOException;
   import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
   import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
  import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
  import javax.jms.*;
  import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;
  public class MessageConsumer extends HttpServlet {
 @Override
  protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     throws ServletException, IOException {
try {
//creating connectionfactory object for way
ConnectionFactory connectionFactory=new     
 ActiveMQConnectionFactory("admin","admin","tcp://localhost:61617");
 //establishing the connection b/w this Application and Activemq
Connection connection=connectionFactory.createConnection();
QueueSession session=(QueueSession) connection.createSession(false, Session.CLIENT_ACKNOWLEDGE);
Queue queue=session.createQueue("MessageTesing");
final QueueReceiver queueReceiver =session.createReceiver(queue);
connection.start();
while (true) {
  Message message = queueReceiver.receive();
  message.acknowledge();
  TextMessage textmsg=(TextMessage) message;
  if (textmsg.getText()=="TestMessage35") {
      RequestDispatcher rd=request.getRequestDispatcher("servletName");
      rd.forward(request, response ) ;
      System.out.println(textmsg.getJMSDestination());
 }
  }
 }
  catch (Exception e) {
  // TODO: handle exception
}
 }
 }
```

I am new to java, can you explain clearly with code.

Thanks.

Comment: Which part of your system is posting the messages? Could you describe what the overall use case is (non techncial)? You can possibly separate the message consuming and processing and the servlet frontend: So a background thread consumes a message, and stores the result in a database. The servlet just gets the result from the database. In your code the servlet blocks (it is waiting for a message), and that's normally not the way it is done.

Comment: I updated my mock-ups, Database part was done by DB team.So I need to assume,I have messages in `Activemq`.

Comment: OK, so based on the message content you call another service dynamically. This service is a servlet or a JSP, and you like send the result of this service back to the browser? During one servlet call there is only one message received? And only one service gets called?

Comment: All my 3 final Applications are not interacting with End-users,it's for internal heavy computations purpose.So their is no result back to the browser.
All my 3 final Applications are forward to another `Jsp` files.I don't want to receive any message until any one of Application process is done out of 3 final Applications. That Application will be select based on XML file data.

Comment: @Beryllium Are you understand?

Comment: @Beryllium Just imagine,If I have Database is in outside,then How will it work standalone Application. So I want to implement web-Application.

Answer (score 2):

Based on these requirements

- When data in the database is changed, a message will be posted on a queue.
- Based on the message content you call another service dynamically.
- That service does some computation, but it's result is not intended for an end-user. It takes 20min.

you could implement a stand-alone application which receives messages synchronously like this (pseudo code):

```
while (true) {
  Message message = queueReceiver.receive();
  TextMessage textmsg = (TextMessage) message;

  if (textmsg.getText().equals("service1")) {
    new Service1().execute();
  } else if (textmsg.getText().equals("service2")) {
    new Service2().execute();
  } else {
    // Show error
  }
  message.acknowledge();
}
```

This job runs continuously.

---

The differences to your proposal

- Using a stand-alone program (with a `main` method) instead of a servlet. A servlet is not suitable (because it does not run continuously)
- Implement your services as normal Java classes; calling JSPs or servlets for processing is not useful. They are intended to implement the presentation layer

*Update*

If your **services** are only reachable over HTTP (this is the case with servlets/JSP), then you could implement these as a **web service**.

Comment: Please look on this question too. I am a great need of your help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19706788/jersey-rest-web-service-with-activemq-middleware-integration